# How can I count strings in a list with while loop in Python?

Tags: python, string, while-loop

Let's say I have a list with 0 or more elements, how can I return the amount of strings in it without using count() or other methods other than a while loop? I tried the code below but it keeps crashing.

```
values = ["one", "two", [], 6]

def count_str(values):
    index = 0
    while index <= len(values):
        if type(values[index]) == str:
            index += 1
    return index
```

Comment: The problem is that you use the same index for iterating over values, and to count strings... So when it's not a string, index does not change, and the loop never ends. Use two variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you got an infinite loop because you only increase the index when it is a string, given that not all instances are, the loop never finishes

try:

```
values = ["one", "two", [], 6]

def count_str(values):
  index = 0
  counter = 0
  while index <= len(values)-1:
    if type(values[index]) == str:
      counter += 1
    index += 1
  return counter

ans = count_str(values)
print(ans)
```